# adding tabs/margin between two variables inside a li

Tags: css

I have a li that looks like this:
li.innerHTML = name + newPrice;

I want there to be padding/spaces between the name and the new price variables without having to go into table formatting. I would basically like the name variable to be all the way to the left, and the newPrice variable all the way to the right. how can I achieve this with CSS? I tried adding spaces but that did not seem ideal. below is my css:

```
#configurator {
 /* margin: 0;
  padding: 0;*/
  font-family: Verdana, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  width: 400px;
  height: auto;
  border-style: solid;
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    /*text-indent: 0px;*/
}

li {
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    /*display: block;*/
    /*width: 10px;*/
     /*text-indent: -1em;*/
}
```

what it looks like now:

[image]

UPDATE:
Thanks to the comment, here is what worked for me:

```
li.innerHTML = '<span class="itemName">' + name + '</span>' + '<span class="itemPrice">' + newPrice + '</span>';
```

CSS:

```
.itemPrice{
float: right;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```

Comment: unless you can do like `li.innerHTML = '<span>' + name + '</span>' + newPrice;` there's nothing more you can do... (then you could `li span { padding-right: 10px; }`

Comment: thanks for nudging me in the right direction :) will update with what I did to fix it

Comment: The OP found his own answer but did not post an answer, so there is no way to mark this question as accepted, so close seems to be the only alternative.

Comment: I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me:

```
li.innerHTML = '<span class="itemName">' + name + '</span>' + '<span class="itemPrice">' + newPrice + '</span>';
CSS:

.itemPrice{
float: right;
padding-right: 15px;
}
```